# Android Vertex Shader says profile does not support texture2d

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, this should hopefully be an easy question for you all. I'm writing an hopefully simple height map (+1,-1) kinda stuff. However, when I try to call `vec4 textColor2 = texture2D(heightmap, a_TexCoordinate);` I get a compile error for my vertex shader.

The dev device is a Nexus 7.

Comment: This link may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398114/vertex-shader-doesnt-run-on-galaxy-tab10-tegra-2

Answer (score 1):

Vertex texture fetching is not necessarily supported by all OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation. The spec defines the minimum number of vertex texture units to be 0. You can do a glGet of GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS to see how many textures you can use in the vertex shader.

Comment: I checked that, and its well over 0.

Comment: I don't have access to a Nexus7 but in another thread, someone reproduced this using a Tegra3 devices (0 GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)